# problem with soaplib (lxml) with apache2 + mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache2, mingw, lxml, cx-oracle

when I launch my application with apache2+modwsgi
I catch

```
Exception Type:    ImportError
Exception Value: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

in line

```
from lxml import etree
```

with Django dev server all works fine
Visual C++ Redistributable 2008 installed

Dependency walker told that msvcrt90.dll is missed
but there is same situation with cx_Oracle, but cx_Oracle's dll loads correct

any ideas?

windows 2003 server 64bit and windows XP sp3 32bit
python 2.7 32 bit
cx_Oracle 5.0.4 32bit

**UPD**:
download libxml2-2.7.7 and  libxslt-1.1.26

tried to build with setup.py build --compiler mingw32

```
Building lxml version 2.3.
Building with Cython 0.14.1.
ERROR: 'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Using build configuration of libxslt
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'src/lxml\lxml.etree.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'lxml.etree' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c src/lxml\lxml.etree.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.et
ree.o -w
writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\etree.def
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\etree.def -LC:\Python27\lib
s -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -llibxslt -llibexslt -llibxml2 -liconv -lzlib -lWS2_32 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\lxml\etree.pyd
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0xd11): undefined reference to `_imp__xmlFree'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0xd24): undefined reference to `_imp__xmlFree'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0x1ee92): undefined reference to `_imp__xmlFree'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0x1eed6): undefined reference to `_imp__xmlFree'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0x2159e): undefined reference to `_imp__xmlMalloc'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0x2e741): undefined reference to `_imp__xmlFree'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0x2e784): undefined reference to `_imp__xmlFree'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0x3f157): undefined reference to `_imp__xmlFree'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0x3f19a): undefined reference to `_imp__xmlFree'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0x3f4ac): undefined reference to `_imp__xmlFree'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0x3f4ef): more undefined references to `_imp__xmlFree' follow
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0xb1ad5): undefined reference to `xsltLibxsltVersion'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\lxml\lxml.etree.o:lxml.etree.c:(.text+0xb1b9a): undefined reference to `xsltDocDefaultLoader'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

**UPD2**:
I understand why import cx_Oracle works fine: cx_Oracle.pyd contains "MSVCRT.dll" dependence etree.pyd doesn't have it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed because of 'msvcrt90.dll'. From somewhere in micro patch revisions of Python 2.6 they stopped building in automatic dependencies on the DLL for extension modules and relied on Python executable doing it. When embedded in other systems however you are then dependent on that executable linking to DLL and in the case of Apache it doesn't. The change in Python has therefore broken many systems which embed Python on Windows and the only solution is for every extension module to have their own dependencies on required DLLs which many don't. The psycopg2 extension was badly affected by this and they have change their builds to add the dependency back in themselves now. You might go searching about the problem as it occurred for psycopg2. One of the solutions was to rebuild extensions with MinGW compiler on Windows instead.